# In a SAS stored process, is there a way to identify the server which called it via ajax

Tags: ajax, sas, sas-stored-process

I have a public Stored process (STP) in which I would like to be able to identify which page is calling it, via ajax.

The STP is momentarily set to run with a guest account and is thus public.

I thought to do it by inserting a secret Key in the STP variables.
But that key can be changed by users in the url.

Is there a method to identify that without leaving the possibility to users to change it?

Maybe there is a reserved STP variable that tells the origin of the request (like the server name or ip or something identifiable)?
But I could not find any among those:

```
_debug
_grafloc
_htcook
_htua
_program
_reqmeth
_rmtaddr
_rmthost
_srvname
_srvport
_url
_userlocale
_username
_version
```

http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/dev_guide/stprocess/reserved.html

Answer (score 1):

Changing my answer as I was previously incorrect.  You CAN get this information (via `_htrefer`) but it requires a [configuration change](http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/dev_guide/stprocess/webappcfg.html#webappprops) to your SAS server.  As per [documentation](http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/dev_guide/stprocess/reserved.html):

> _HTREFER:  Specifies the address of the referring page. This variable is not set by default but can be enabled in the params.config
>   file.

It's worth noting that no method can ever be 100% reliable as end users can always manipulate their requests.